# Why is "1 << 32" equal to 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If 1 is 32 bits then `1 << 32` is equal to `0`.

If 1 is 64 bits then `1<< 32` is `4294967296`.

So where is 1 coming from in JS? is it undefined behaviour?

https://jsfiddle.net/xn2hr7fa/1/

Comment: Javascript only supports 32-bit numbers with bitshifts.

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'll notice that `<<` only operates on 32-bit signed integers, never 64-bit values.

Comment: @Amy ok so the result should be 0 not 1 then

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I had to guess: because your question is [literally the first line of documentation about bit operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) so it shows you did no research for your question.

Comment: @Josh, no, because again, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators):  "The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the low five bits will be used."

Comment: @Paulpro it *documents* the behaviour. So it's a wiki but also documentation.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 W3Schools chose their name to help them sound more "official"; consequently, people frequently think they are associated with W3C.  They aren't as bad as they used to be, but they're still bad.  They used to be worse.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, the relevant [part of the spec is here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-bitwise-shift-operators)

Answer (score 7):

As is the case with many languages, the left shift operator only uses the five least significant bits (treating the shift distance as a 32-bit int). Refer to Step 7 [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.1).

Thus:

`1 << 32 === 1 << (32 & 0x1f)` which is `1 << 0 === 1`

`1 << 33 === 1 << (33 & 0x1f)` which is `1 << 1 === 2`

`1 << 34 === 1 << (34 & 0x1f)` which is `1 << 2 === 4`

and so on.

Comment: Masking all but 5 lowest bits is not "a 32-bit int".  But then, I guess I'm the only one who thinks this "quasi-rotate" is a really stupid idea.

Comment: @ScottHunter It is still a 32-bit int with at least 27 leading zero bits; but I wasn't referring to how it is treated after the masking, it's important to know that it is treated as an int for the masking, since though the number really is an IEEE 754 double. This is consistent with how bitwise `&` works in JavaScript too.

Comment: What other languages treat x<<34 and x<<2 as equivalent?  What semantic (as opposed to implementation) justification would support this?

Comment: @ScottHunter Java does, but I wrongly assumed C/C++ do as well (instead it is undefined behaviour). I believe there are other languages that do, but I can't name any right now.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't personally like this behaviour, and I agree that the result being `0` makes more semantic sense. I prefer what Python does, which is allow you to shift arbitrarily without losing significant one-bits. You can do that in JavaScript soon with BigInt (`1n << 5000n`).